# What's an example of a group with equivalent uniform structures where multiplication is not uniformly continuous?

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

Say we have a topological group $G$.  It's easy to see that if $\cdot: G \times G \rightarrow G$ is uniformly continuous (with respect to either the right or left uniformity), then $G$ must have equivalent uniform structures.  I figure the converse is probably false, on the basis that otherwise I would have seen this mentioned somewhere.  But I can't think of an example, because I don't know many examples of topological groups, and all the examples I can think of with equivalent uniformities are built out of compact, abelian, or discrete groups, all of which do have uniformly continuous multiplication!  Can anyone give me a counterexample?  Or are these indeed equivalent?

Comment: Exercise 1.8.c on p.79 of Arhangel'skii-Tkachenko, *[Topological groups and related structures](http://books.google.ch/books?id=B785AETmFKEC)* asks the reader to prove that uniform continuity of the multiplication mapping is equivalent to the group being balanced (having equivalent left and right uniformities).

Comment: ...huh. That's a surprise.  You should post that as an answer so I can accept it and consider this closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I haven't done the exercise carefully myself (and I'm not really in the mood to), but on Harry's request I'm posting it as an answer.

---

According to Exercise 1.8.c on page 79 of Arhangel'skii-Tkachenko, *[Topological groups and related structures](http://books.google.ch/books?id=B785AETmFKEC)*,  the following are equivalent for a topological group (*uniformly continuous* means uniformly continuous with respect to *both* the left and the right uniform structures):

1. The multiplication map $G^{2} \to G$ is uniformly continuous.
2. The multiplication map $G^{n} \to G$ is uniformly continuous for all $n \geq 2$.
3. The group is *balanced* in the sense that the left and right uniformities are equivalent.

Since you're interested in $3 \implies 1$ that's good enough (provided that it is true).

Comment: I would say that there is not much more to it than the fact that inversion is uniformly continuous on a balanced group.

Comment: Yeah, I feel silly - this is actually easy, but I miscalculated when trying to prove it and figured it probably wasn't true.

Comment: @Harry: Well, this happens to all of us :) Once we're convinced of the wrong track, we often need a nudge from outside... Glad I could help in that respect.